# python argparse option string not complete but value is assigned

Tags: python, argparse

Argparse doesn't seem to check for entire string of option to assign the value. Is this a bug or intended one? What are the use cases for this if this is intended?

Run the following program using python3 test.py **-test** "testing"

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-testurl', dest='testurl')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

Output is

Namespace(testurl='testing')

Comment: From the docs, `allow_abbrev - Allows long options to be abbreviated if the abbreviation is unambiguous. (default: True)`

Comment: Allowing abbreviations was the original intent.  The addition of the parameter is relatively recent, in version 3.5.  And even that required some refinement in version 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use double dash (`--`) in options and make `allow_abbrev=False` in parser to force the exact argument to be parsed [[reference: argument parser documentation]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects):

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
    parser.add_argument('--testurl', dest='testurl')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```

Output:

```
> python3 df_reg.py --test "testing" 
usage: df_reg.py [-h] [--testurl TESTURL]
df_reg.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --test testing

> python3 df_reg.py --testurl "testing"
Namespace(testurl='testing')
```

References:

- [Argument parser documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects)